# Oracle - Query to retrieve last day of month for all months from current and previous year

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, recursive-query

From JAN-19 til OCT-2020, what would be the query to retrieve every last day for each month starting from JAN-19 til this current year?

Expected Output

```
Last Day 
--------
31-JAN-2019
28-FEB-2019
31-MAR-2019
...
31-JAN-2020
29-FEB-2020
31-MAR-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SQL> select last_day(add_months(date'2019-01-01',level-1)) dt from dual connect by level<=24;

DT
-------------------
2019-01-31 00:00:00
2019-02-28 00:00:00
2019-03-31 00:00:00
2019-04-30 00:00:00
2019-05-31 00:00:00
2019-06-30 00:00:00
2019-07-31 00:00:00
2019-08-31 00:00:00
2019-09-30 00:00:00
2019-10-31 00:00:00
2019-11-30 00:00:00
2019-12-31 00:00:00
2020-01-31 00:00:00
2020-02-29 00:00:00
2020-03-31 00:00:00
2020-04-30 00:00:00
2020-05-31 00:00:00
2020-06-30 00:00:00
2020-07-31 00:00:00
2020-08-31 00:00:00
2020-09-30 00:00:00
2020-10-31 00:00:00
2020-11-30 00:00:00
2020-12-31 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use standard recursive queries for this:

```
with cte (dt) as (
    select date '2019-01-01' dt from dual
    union all select add_months(dt, 1) from cte where dt < add_months(sysdate, -1)
)
select last_day(dt) dt from cte
```

This generates all end-of-months dates from January 2019 until the current month (included).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=121a54cdfd55cd0ade9495a9f4496993)**